# WebSocket получение большого сообщения

Tags: c#, json

При получении сообщения от сокета оно обрезается. Получаю примерно 680,000 символов, хотя должно прийти сообщение примерно в 3 раза больше.
Мысли кончились, что я делаю не так?

```
var webSocketClient = new ClientWebSocket();
var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();

await webSocketClient.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://ws-feed.gdax.com"), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (webSocketClient.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
    var requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        type = "subscribe",
        product_ids = new[] { "BTC-USD" },
        channels = new[] { "level2", "ticker" }
    });
    var requestBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);
    var subscribeRequest = new ArraySegment<byte>(requestBytes);
    var sendCancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
    await webSocketClient.SendAsync(subscribeRequest, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, sendCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    while (webSocketClient.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        var receiveCancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(1024 * 1000))
        {
            var receiveBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[128]);
            WebSocketReceiveResult webSocketReceiveResult;
            do
            {
                webSocketReceiveResult = await webSocketClient.ReceiveAsync(receiveBuffer, receiveCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await stream.WriteAsync(receiveBuffer.Array, receiveBuffer.Offset, receiveBuffer.Count);
            } while (!webSocketReceiveResult.EndOfMessage);

            var message = stream.ToArray().Where(b => b != 0).ToArray();

            string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message, 0, message.Length);
            Debug.WriteLine(str);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Докопался до истины:
вместо строчки

```
await stream.WriteAsync(receiveBuffer.Array, receiveBuffer.Offset, receiveBuffer.Count);
```

надо ставить

```
await stream.WriteAsync(receiveBuffer.Array, receiveBuffer.Offset, webSocketReceiveResult.Count);
```

так как иначе вместо чтения сообщения до конца я читаю до конца лишь буфер.